# ggplot: order barplots in facets with same color legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

With dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- structure(list(dept = c("A", "B", "C"), 
n = c(70908L, 50004L, 294614L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("dept", "n"))

df2 <- structure(list(dept = c("A", "B", "D", "E"), 
n = c(544L, 684L, 375L, 1191L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("dept", "n"))

> df1
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   dept      n
  <chr>  <int>
1     A  70908
2     B  50004
3     C 294614

> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   dept     n
  <chr> <int>
1     A   544
2     B   684
3     D   375
4     E  1191
```

I want to create an ordered barplot in facets with same fill/legend. Here is what I can get so far:

```
df <- rbind(df1 %>% mutate(source = 1),
       df2 %>% mutate(source = 2))

df %>% ggplot(aes(reorder(dept, n), n, fill = dept)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~source, scales = "free")
```

[Rplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojrzX.png)

how to make `reorder` function works at each facet?

Comment: So in facet2 you want to start from green?

Comment: @PoGibas. From the largest to smallest. So ideally it should be ordered as: E -> B -> A -> D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order values in both facets create new column `var3` and `reorder` using it. After this just change labels in `scale_x_discrete` from `var3` back to `dept`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- rbind(df1 %>% mutate(source = 1),
            df2 %>% mutate(source = 2)) %>%
    mutate(var3 = paste(source, dept))
ggplot(df, aes(reorder(var3, n), n, fill = dept)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    xlab("dept") +
    facet_wrap(~ source, scales = "free") +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = df$var3, labels = df$dept)
```

[image]

Comment: I get a wrong plot. Labels at `scale_x_discrete` are not ordered correctly.

Comment: @LiangquanZhou can you please explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: I tried your code. The last line `scale_x_discrete(labels = df$dept)` seems not working properly. Mine is showing the left side labels are: C -> B -> A, and the right side labels are A -> C -> B -> A

Comment: I got it. The last line could be: 
`scale_x_discrete(breaks = df$var3, labels = df$dept)`